# How to make an array of images in Qt?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I want to make an array of images in Qt, but am not getting any idea how to approach for the same.

I would like to load the images from the array in widget on an event.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Actually your idea is not clear here. there can be two scenarios 1. Store images in local disk and keep path in the system. 2.Keep image as binary data in application itself. Which of method you mean here?

Comment: Please rewrite the question, much more details is needed... Is the problem in loading the images, or is it creating the array, or is it actually how to write a loop in C++? "What have you tried?", meaning, attach your current code, and show which part you have problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QImage img1("C:\\img1.jpg");
QImage img2("C:\\img2.jpg");
QImage img3("C:\\img3.jpg");
```

Using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<QImage> img_array;
img_array.push_back(img1);
img_array.push_back(img2);
img_array.push_back(img3);
```

Or `QVector`:

```
QVector<QImage> img_array;
img_array.push_back(img1);
img_array.push_back(img2);
img_array.push_back(img3);
```

Answer (score 3):

Qt's `QImage` uses implicit data sharing, so you can just pass them around and use them in data structures, like you'd use for example `int` or `QString`.

So, do `QImage` array like you'd do `int` array...

However, if you don't want *array* specifically, the most common solution and probably the best fit for your case in Qt is `QList` (note: it is not linked list, it's resizable array, so pretty much like `std::vector`):

```
QList<QImage> myImages;
```

Comment: If it's like a vector why not using it? or QVector ? does QList have avantages over it ?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply make a QList of QImages. 
So i will do like this:

```
 // for simplicity
 typedef QList<QImage> QImageList;

 // allocate the list
 QImageList imageList;

 // create a list where you will put paths of your images
 QStringList paths;

 // then create the list of images     
 for(int i=0;i<paths.size();++i){
      imageList.push_back(QImage(paths.at(i));
 }
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: oh yes u are right! do you tell to *karlphillip* to do the same or do I?

Comment: His post didn't end up in the low quality post queue.

Comment: but  you have read his answer and you can see that was the same.. now i have explained anyway..

Comment: ...starting answer with a `typedef` is not something I'd do "for simplicity" when the non-typedefed form is already this simple ;). And I'd especally avoid custom typedefs which look like they were Qt typedefs, so I'd `typedef QList<QImage> ImageList;` if I wanted that typedef. And in Qt code, I'd use `append()` instead of `push_back()`, because latter does not follow general Qt naming conventions. But, matters of opinion, feel free to disagree.

Comment: i think it does look better when you declare *QImageList* instead of *QList<QImage>* and i think is more readable. anyway everyone have his own style.